# Проблема кодировки при парсинге html-страницы на python

Tags: python, парсер, pycharm

Учусь парсить на питоне с html-страницы. Однако вместо 'Главная страница блога' выходит 'Р“Р»Р°РІРЅР°СЏ СЃС‚СЂР°РЅРёС†Р° Р±Р»РѕРіР°'. Хэлп ми!)

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('testing.html') as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

title = soup.find('title')
print(title)
```

Вот что указано в начале html кода:

'html lang="ru"><meta charset="UTF-8"'

Comment: вероятно истинная кодировка windows-1251

Comment: Попробуйте разные кодировки при чтении файла указать. Например `encoding='utf-8'` либо `cp1251`

Comment: @CrazyElf а куда конкретно нужно кодировку вписать? Я пробую, но получаю что-то типа xa0\xc2\xbb\....

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо! Разобрался! Просто указал кодировку with open('testing.html') as file:
    src = file.read().encode(encoding='cp1251')

Comment: Ну вообще по-нормальному нужно при открытии файла указывать `open('testing.html', encoding='cp1251')` но возможно у вас более сложный случай )

Answer (score 0):

В CMD выполните intl.cpl и там укажите глобально UTF-8.

Вкладка "Дополнительно" -> "Изменить язык системы" -> установите флажок "Бета-версия: Использовать Юникод (UTF-8) для поддержки языка во всем мире"

Answer (score 0):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('testing.html', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    src = file.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, 'lxml')

title = soup.find('title')
print(title)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]